# Simple Mac software to batch organize & rename photos by date

Tags: osx, file-management, photography

I'm looking for software that can take a bunch of photos from an SD card, copy them to my laptop, organize them into folders Photos/YYYY/MM/DD, and rename them YYYY-MM-DD-SEQ.ext, based on the photo's capture metadata. Of course ideally with customizable formats. I'm on Mac so can use either macOS GUI or most *nix scripts

My previous solution was the import dialog in ON1 Photo Raw - see the image. As I've moved away from ON1 for my RAW editing, I'd like a standalone piece of software that can provide the same thing - it's a simple thing I haven't been able to find a satisfactory tool for. There seem to be Windows tools but I haven't seen Mac ones. I'd of course prefer gratis and FOSS, but I'm not married to either.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, after digging through more software rec threads etc, I believe I've finally found what I was looking for! [Transnomino](https://www.transnomino.com) allows creating a rename pipeline, with rules for setting path, filename, sequence number, etc based on various rules and metadata. I've only played played with it briefly but it seems like exactly what I wanted.